# How to use an Exception's attributes in Python?

Tags: python, exception, attributes

Is there a way to use the attributes/properties of an `Exception` object in a try-except block in Python?

For example in Java we have:

```java
try {
    // Some code
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Here we can use some of the attributes of "e"
}
```

What equivalent in Python would give me a reference to `e`?

Comment: Why the close votes? This is a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: I too don't understand the "not a real question" moderation.   The question is very specific, and Ashwini Chaudhary gave a good answer.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use the `as` statement. You can read more about this in [Handling Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```py
>>> try:
...     print(a)
... except NameError as e:
...     print(dir(e))  # print attributes of e
...
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
 '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__',
 '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__traceback__', 'args',
 'with_traceback']
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html):

```
class MyError(Exception):
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value

   def __str__(self):
      return repr(self.value)

try:
     raise MyError(2*2)
except MyError as e:
     print 'My exception occurred, value:', e.value
```

Answer (score 9):

Sure, there is:

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception as e:
    # Here we can use some the attribute of "e"
```